# PHP Type Annotation for functions?

Tags: php

In PHP it's common to type annotate variables like this:

```
  /**
   * @var boolean
   */
  protected $isLoaded;
```

But what about the return types in functions? Does PHP Type Annotation support the return type of a function?

If so, how can I annotate the return type of the function in class diagram

> -getName(): String

?

I would expect something like:

```
  /**
   * @return String
   */
  private function getName() {}
```

But it's ignored.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: ah thanks, I was looking on the wrong place: http://php-annotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AnnotationLibrary.html?highlight=return
and couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would just be:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
private function getName(): string {}
```

The annotation is optional at this point.